# Joomla 2.5 installation

Tags: joomla, wamp

when i installing joomla 2.5 on WAMP server it was stack at level 4 (database)

**Server Configuration**

Apache Version : 2.4.4
PHP Version :    5.4.12
MySQL Version :  5.6.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, it was in 'PHP.in' file in 'wamp->PHP',there is a 'max_input_time = 30' i changed is 'max_input_time = 240' and restart the server and install joomla, then again change it to max_input_time = 30 it work.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should check:
1) Are your login and password correct.
2) Are you connecting to the right server and port (sometimes it is for example localhost:3306)

Also try to install your WAMP to the root folder. e.g. C:\WAMP